# How to use microphone in KVM, virt-manager based Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualization, microphone, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 (64-bit) as host and Q4OS(32-bit) as guest. I have added camera from USB host devices and hence it works now on using google meet in virtual machine.

But I am still unable to use mic there and meet says that my mic is not working. What can I do? (Please note that I haven't added mic from usb host device as I can't find it there).

Answer (score 1):

hello I bought usb headset with microphone and via spice I share it in virtual instance. Than it work.